# Serving flask app on subdirectory nginx + uwsgi

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am try to deploy flask on a sub directory on my website, this script is super light weight and doesn't need (actually it can't) to roll into the main project. How ever when I go to the end point, I get a 404 error from flask (can confirm that it is flask because the log shows activity). I am passing `uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /upload;` and `uwsgi_modifier1 30;` in my nginx config file, but that doesn't seem to work. How can I get uwsgi to serve my flask application on an nginx sub location (subdir)?

Here is my nginx config (the /upload location is where the trouble is):

```
upstream django {
    server app0.api.xyz.com:9002;
}

server {
    listen      443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/api_xyz.key;

    charset     utf-8;
    server_name dev.api.xyz.com;

    location / {
            uwsgi_pass django;
            include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }

    location /media  {
            alias /var/xyzdata;
    }

    location /upload {
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/sockets/upload.sock;
        uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /upload;
        uwsgi_modifier1 30;
    }
}
```

my uwsgi.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir           = /home/ubuntu/uploadFlask
module          = images
callable        = app
socket          = /var/sockets/upload.sock
master          = true
processes       = 10
vacuum          = true
uid             = www-data
gid             = www-data
daemonize       = /var/log/uploads/error.log
```

and finally my entire flask app:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for,Response, jsonify
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import time

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/var/xyzdata'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

@app.route('/<user>', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file(user):
    file = request.files['file']
    if file:
            file_id = str(time.time()).replace('.','_')
            filename = "{0}/images/{1}.jpg".format(user, file_id)
            path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            d = os.path.dirname(path)
            if not os.path.exists(d):
                    os.makedirs(d)
            file.save(path)
            return jsonify(physical_path=path, virtual_path=filename,
                           id=file_id)

@app.route('/delete/<user>/<id>/', methods=['POST'])
def delete_file(user, id):
    pass
```

the point of this script is to upload images to my static server. My actual application sits on a separate server and thats why this can't sit there.

Basically what i want is to be able to go to dev.api.xyz.com/upload/123/ and hit upload_file. I'm expecting a 405 error in the browser, because it is restricted to POST. But I am getting a 404 error. Here is a sample output from the flask/uwsgi log:

```
[pid: 27900|app: 0|req: 4/5] 50.199.33.84 () {40 vars in 669 bytes} [Wed Jul  1 01:03:51 2015] GET /upload/things@things.com => generated 233 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 72 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

So flask is getting hit but the url matching is not working. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've found so far would be using the `mount` option of uwsgi. In your config add the line

```
mount = /upload=<scriptname>
```

Solution courtesy of https://serverfault.com/questions/461946

Answer (score 2):

Best and quick solution for me

```
location ~ /upload(/.*) {
    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/var/sockets/upload.sock;
    uwsgi_param PATH_INFO "$1";
}
```

Hope this can help you. cheers

Comment: The same without regex location: `location /upload/ { rewrite ^/upload(.*) $1 break; include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; uwsgi_pass unix:/var/sockets/upload.sock; }`

Comment: In on a first attempt the answer by Ivan gave me the desired behaviour. But later, even though the routes were working fine, I was having issues serving static content. So, thanks to this answer (https://serverfault.com/a/644172) it was noted that this was because I had regex locations in the same server block, which apparently take precedence over prefixed locations! So then the regex location worked better. I still had to add  app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] and 
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(
    app.wsgi_app, x_for=1, x_proto=1, x_host=1, x_prefix=1
)
whithout which the prefix wouldn't work.